# regex replace, look ahead

Tags: javascript, regex

since javascript doesn't support look behinds, i had problem creating this regex.

I have a string `{sadsada` and I want to put an `"` after `{` if and only if `{` seems to exist to the left a random alphabet character (case insensitive)

and I want to do it for all occurences.

so basically,  this `{asdadafafafsa` will turn into `{"sadafsafa`

I tried with

```
string.replace(/{.*/g, '{"')
```

but this also removes the alphabetic characters to the right. and i want to achieve this with one regex expression only without any before hand checks.

Thank you in advance

Comment: JavaScript *does* support lookbehinds in regular expressions now. All major browsers support it, as well as Node.js. See: https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind The last holdout was Safari (iOS, desktop), but has supported lookbehinds since Safari 16.4.

Comment: Why lookbehind then? Use a lookahead: `string.replace(/{(?=[a-z])/gi, '{"')`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Are you trying to convert [JSON5](https://json5.org/) to JSON?

Answer (score -1):

> *"... since javascript doesn't support look behinds, i had problem creating this regex. ..."*

Yes it does.

> *"... I have a string `{sadsada` and I want to put an `"` after `{` if and only if `{` seems to exist to the left a random alphabet character (case insensitive) ..."*

You can match this index with the following pattern.

```
(?<={)(?=[a-z]+)
```

Here is an example.

```js
var s = '{sadsada'
s = s.replace(/(?<={)(?=[a-zA-Z]+)/, '"')
console.log(s)
```

Comment: The advantage of matching as Wiktor suggested makes the pattern also work when the Javascript engine does not support a lookbehind. Also note that `(?=[a-zA-Z]+)` could be just `(?=[a-zA-Z])`